# Building object files which depend on other object files (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class, base-class, object-files

I have a file, Matching.cxx, which contains some class method definitions and some other functions.  It contains calls to many other classes.
In my makefile I create object files for al of the other classes first and then attempt to make Matching.o.  However when I do this I get an error for each appearance of these other classes.
It may also be important that in the region throwing compilation errors I have created an abstract base object and I'm inheriting from some derived object based on some conditionals.
I have a feeling that it is to do with not linking the object files together correctly, at present I am just making each of the other classes makefiles (this goes fine), then making the Matching.o (this fails) then I would link them all together in to the final executable.
Clearly something is wrong!

Any advice greatly appreciated
Cheers
Jack

More details:

```
//declare base object:
CPPProcess* process;
if(something is true) process = new CPPProcess2j_dd();
else if...
```

Errors look like:

```
Matching.C: In function ‘CPPProcess* GenerateMGProcess(int, int, int, int*)’:
Matching.C:501: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘CPPProcess*’
Matching.C:501: error: expected `;' before ‘CPPProcess2j_dd’
```

Comment: Shows the errors and the lines of code the errors point to.

Comment: The reason I think it might be a compilation mistake is that before I used matching.C as my 'main' routine and it compiled fine.  But now matching.C just contains stuff used in a larger project

Comment: And CPPProcess2j_dd is a ?

Comment: It is one of the derived classes so its definition is something along the lines of:
class CPPProcess2j_dd : public CPPProcess{STUFF}

Comment: how about showing the offending line and other _relevant_ code?

Comment: Please see above for both?